# Azure node.js server and Hololens

Tags: node.js, azure, unity-game-engine, websocket, hololens

I am trying to connect to my Node.js server that I have hosted as a webapp on Azure.  I'm not sure what I am doing wrong or missing here.

My setup:
Azure account with event hub/iot hub/webapp/storage
Simulated devices that send data to iot hub
node.js server that connects to iothub to send data to Unity3D.
Unity3D app that receives the data and displays it - ultimately on Hololens.

Currently I use this code on my local machine and run without flaw -

```
    const Receiver = require('azure-iothub-receiver');
var io = require('socket.io')
var shortid = require('shortid');

var fs = require("fs"),
  WebSocket = require("ws"),
    WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
console.log(PORT);
console.log('Server started');

const options = {
  connectionString: 'XXXXXXXXX' 
};
const receiver = new Receiver(options);

var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: PORT });
wss.on('connection', function(ws){
    console.log("Client connected");
    if (ws.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
    var message = "Hello!";
    console.log("Send:", message);
}
      receiver.on('data', (message) => {
                console.log('body:', message.body.temperature);
              ws.send(message.body.temperature, { binary: false, mask: false });
        });
        ws.on("close", function () {
            console.log("Client disconnected");
        });
        ws.on("error", function (error) {
            console.log("Error: %s", error);
    })

});
```

In unity I am using DeadlyFingers code from [here](https://github.com/Unity3dAzure/UnityWebSocketDemo).  In unity I enter the IP address of my webapp but it doenst connect.

I'm not sure what is happening here. does the server need to bee configured differently when its deployed from azure webaps compared to my local machine?

Am I connecting to it incorrectly?

Thanks,
Jared

Comment: I don't know DeadlyFingers, but if you make the request by your self using the WWW class I believe it should works. WWW Sample: https://github.com/sGambolati/HoloWorkShop-Ex4/blob/master/Assets/Scripts/CognitiveServicesClient.cs#L108

Comment: great, I'll give it a try

Comment: Did you find solution for it, if yes please let me know I am in the same situation. My goal is to connect to hololens device using socket io and perform the operatons like reboot , shutdown hololens  , Any github repo would really help me. Thanks

Comment: Azure basic service plans does not allow web sockets at all from my experience.